# Identify a Resizable Div if it Maintains its Aspect Ratio When Resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have this `HTML` code below:

```
<div id="myid_templates_editor_text_1" class="myid_templates_editor_element myid_templates_editor_text ui-resizable ui-draggable" style="width: 126.79999999999998px; height: 110px; position: absolute; left: 196px; top: 76px; -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); border: hidden;">
     <div class="myid_templates_editor_text_dynamic_part"><p><strong>dsdasadsd</strong></p></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
     <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
     <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
</div>
```

I made the `div` with an id `myid_templates_editor_text_1` resizable and maintain its aspect ratio, through `Jquery Plugin`.

```
$('#myid_templates_editor_text_1').resizable({
    animate: true,          
    aspectRatio: true
});
```

Sometimes, I made the functionality 'Maintain Aspect Ratio' disabled. See code below:

```
$('#myid_templates_editor_text_1').resizable({
    animate: true,          
    aspectRatio: false
});
```

How will I determine if the `div`'s maintaining aspect ratio just by looking to the `HTML Code` or `javascript` or `jquery` function? Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can get option values as normal with many jQuery UI widgets using the [`option()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#method-option) method.  See example from the jQuery UI docs for [`resizeable()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-aspectRatio):

```
// Getter
var aspectRatio = $( ".selector" ).resizable( "option", "aspectRatio" );
```

So for your case:

```
var aspectRatio = $('#myid_templates_editor_text_1').resizable( "option", "aspectRatio" );
```

**JFIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/xnt15Lza/

**DEMO:**

```js
$(function() {
  $("div.green").resizable({
    aspectRatio: true
  });
  $("div.blue").resizable({
    aspectRatio: false
  });
  var aspectRatio = $("div.green").resizable("option", "aspectRatio");
  alert('green div aspectRatio set to: ' + aspectRatio);
  var aspectRatio = $("div.blue").resizable("option", "aspectRatio");
  alert('blue div aspectRatio set to: ' + aspectRatio);
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
}
div.green {
  background-color: green;
}
div.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="green"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I display the aspectRatio variable. It says '[object Object]'. Im expecting a boolean value. Either true or false.

Comment: Not sure what's going wrong for you but it works.  See updated answer with demo.

Comment: Thanks, something in my code had mess up. Your answer is right.